# Decimals in schema generated by EF being set to 0 decimal places?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I've noticed that whenever I generate a database schema from an EF model that includes `decimal` fields the SQL type used is `decimal(18,0)` - this causes all decimal values to be effectively truncated to integers on persistence to the database.

Is there a configuration option or setting that can be applied to control the default precision of all SQL decimal types that are generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change scale and precision in the designer. Select the property in your entity and in Properties window change values as you need.

[image]

Comment: This does allow you to set the scale and precision for each individual field, but is there a way to set a more useful default for all decimals?

Comment: If you want to change default value you can modify T4 template responsible for generating SQL.